# Create a Blob and open it in the browser with a desired URL

Tags: javascript, html, blobs

I have written the following code to create a file using a blob and open it automatically(instead of downloading) in the browser(Chrome).

```
 var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "text/html"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url);
       window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = { x: 42, s: "hello, world", d: new Date() },
    fileName = "my-download.json";

saveData(data, fileName);
```

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cW7W5/611[1](http://jsfiddle.net/cW7W5/611/)

The file open successfully in a new browser window as

> blob:http%3A//fiddle.jshell.net/83999d68-4d79-4a06-a83d-e40a8b1f9681

But what I want to open it in a url that I specified. For example

> blob:http%3A//fiddle.jshell.net/**exapmle.txt**

Comment: you can't customize blob URLs

Comment: Ok Thanks. Is there any work around to get rid of the ugly url ending like .../83999d68-4d79-4a06-a83d-e40a8b1f9681

Comment: sure, you can call eg. `history.replaceState(0, 0, "/myFancyPath/FacyFile.ext")` right after you set the url of the window to whatever makes sense to you or your users.

Comment: Can you please show that solution in teh jsfiddle? Thanks